# How process part of method one request at a time in aspcore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, concurrency

i have to increment a column in database, this increment can depend other column for example increment by user, i´am using jmeter to send several request in the same time, i tried to use lock but dont works fine, how can i freeze part of  method?

```
public override DepositoProduto Save(DepositoProduto entity)
    {
        lock (entity)
        {
            using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //here auto increment
                entity.Codigo = All().OrderByDescending(x => x.Codigo).Select(x => x.Codigo).First() + 1;

                //here commit to the database
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: You can't lock on `entity` because it's likely a different instance every time this method is called. Created a static class level variable that you can lock on.

Comment: any example of this ?

Comment: i tried to create a variable  private static readonly object _lock = new object(); an add  lock (_lock ), but all my request are freeze, and dont save

Comment: What are your *actual* requirements for the number?. Any requirement that they must be *sequential* and *without gaps* will tend to severely limit the ability for the service to scale. If you merely require uniqueness, let the database do that for you with identity/autoincrement/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SemaphoreSlim` on singleton-scoped or static object. That could be your repository or whatever this is, or if you need to keep that in request-scope, then you can utilize an alternate helper class to simply handle this incrementing process. Semaphores are fairly straight forward to use; you basically just set a static ivar typed as `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
```

Here, the `1` specifies that only one thing can enter the semaphore at a time, which is what you want for this particular scenario. You can use other numbers here in different scenarios to basically rate-limit. Then, you wrap the code you need to run with:

```
_semaphore.Wait(); // or await _semaphore.WaitAsync()

// code protected by semaphore here

_semaphore.Release();
```

The semaphore has a counter. When `Wait` is called, the semaphore ups the counter by 1 and then if there's nothing else waiting, it will return and allow the subsequent code to process. If the counter is already higher than the max (which is 1 here), then it will not return until the counter is decreased below the max threshold. That decrement happens via `Release`, which is called after your code completes. Essentially, this creates a type of queue, with other threads waiting for their chance to run the code protected by the semaphore. That then allows you to ensure that only one `Save` call at a time is doing anything and thus, your increment transaction will always work.

It's similar to locking, especially with a count of 1, but semaphores are thread-safe whereas locks are not. If something else already has a lock, then you'll simply get an exception trying to create the lock and you'll have to recover manually by implementing a wait and retry pattern, circuit breaker, etc. Semaphores ease this by not being bound to any particular thread.

Comment: i tried use SemaphoreSlim but all my requests are freezing, and dont process

Comment: Well, all I can say is that something about your usage was wrong. If you want to post a new question with that code, I or someone else can take a look at it.

Comment: SemaphoreSlim  sounds perfect please take a look https://ibb.co/mqvhGzF